# Building Docker container that calls CGO from python

Tags: python, docker, cgo

My main app is python, and I have some Go code that I want to call from python inside the Docker container. Usually I have compiled the Go code using CGO with `go build -buildmode=c-shared -o dllname.dll`, and used that from other languages. In python I can run the dll using the `ctypes` module and `cdll.LoadLibrary` (on windows).

In my mind, this is how it would work in a Dockerfile (I am new to Docker):

1. Install Go
2. Install Go dependencies/libraries
3. Install a suitable C compiler
4. Copy the Go/Cgo source files into the container
5. Compile the Go/Cgo code into a shared binary using `CGO_ENABLED=1 go build -buildmode=c-shared`
6. Copy python source files into container
7. Assign python entry point with CMD

I have made many futile attempts at making such a Dockerfile. Is this doable?

Comment: Yes this is definitely possible. You can start with go's official docker images, like `golang:1.17.2-bullseye`. fyi bullseye is a version of debian linux.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to that image, I tried it and got a little further. The compilation of the cgo code seems to work now. I'm not quite getting it all to work yet, probably because I don't know how to structure the Dockerfile correctly as a multi stage build. (I end up with python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.9.so.1.0)

Comment: great to hear you’re making progress. Can you include your full Dockerfile in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it to work using the golang:1.17.2-bullseye image as suggested by jakub. This is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.17.2-bullseye as builder
WORKDIR /go/src/app
COPY ./lib/cgo .
RUN go get ./...
RUN CGO_ENABLED=1 go build -buildmode=c-shared -o cgolibname.so .

FROM python:3.9
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./appname .
COPY --from=builder /go/src/app/cgolibname.so .
CMD [ "python", "main.py" ]
```